# How to Add Secret yaml in Azure DevOps pipeline for AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying out few things in AKS. Right now I am trying to release to AKS through Azure DevOps. But I have a doubt that I have 3 yaml files (ConfigMap, Deployment and Secret) and I mentioned the below in deployment.yaml file

```
envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: webinar-web-app-secret
        - configMapRef:
            name: webinar-web-app-configmap
```

Right now my release file looks like this. Please guide me how to add the secret.yaml file in the pipeline

```
trigger: 
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
resources:
- repo: self

stages:
- stage: 'Deployment_AKS_Prod'
  displayName: 'Deploy To AKS prod'
  jobs:
    - deployment: Release
      environment: 'test-aks.prod'
      displayName: 'Release'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - checkout: self

            - task: Kubernetes@1
              displayName: Deploying Manifests into AKS
              inputs:
                connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
                azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'aks'
                azureResourceGroup: 'test-rg'
                kubernetesCluster: 'test-aks'
                namespace: 'prod'
                command: 'apply'
                useConfigurationFile: true
                configuration: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment/webinar-app.yaml'
                secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
                useConfigMapFile: true
                configMapFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment/configmap.yaml'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one file deployed under the configuration input on the Kubernetes@1 task by specifying a directory instead . (so in your case, you can  have the yaml files under one folder but specifying the kind they are.

([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-v1?view=azure-pipelines#:~:text=configuration%20%2D%20File%20path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-v1?view=azure-pipelines#:%7E:text=configuration%20%2D%20File%20path))

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#describing-a-kubernetes-object

Comment: If I specify the folder of my yaml do they deploy in alphabetical order??

Comment: Yes that should be the case, best append a prefix with 01.deployment.yml , 02.config.yml etc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33112862)